# Retrieve nodes value from graph

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, recursion, graph

I have a graph define by a dictionary:

```
{'A':['B', 'C'], 'B': ['D', 'E'], 'C': [], 'D': [], 'E': []}
```

Each of those nodes correspond to a column in a panda dataframe say

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 | E1 |
| A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 | E2 |

I would like to traverse each branch of the graph and retrieve each node's value from the dataframe for a given row, for instance for row 1 so that I have the following result:

```
[
[A1 , B1, D1], 
[A1, B1, E1], 
[A1, C1]
]
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what the connection is between the graph defined in your dictionary and the result that you're looking for

Comment: I am looking for a way of traversing the graph and returning a list of list of all the values that each branch contains (stored in the dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a bit underspecified, since graphs can be pretty complex. For your example this could work:

```
G = {'A': ['B', 'C'], 'B': ['D', 'E'], 'C': [], 'D': [], 'E': []}

paths = []
stack = [[next(iter(G))]]
while stack:
    path = stack.pop()
    extension = [
        path + [node] for node in G[path[-1]] if node not in path
    ]
    if extension:
        stack.extend(reversed(extension))
    else:
        paths.append(path)
```

Result:

```
[['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'E'], ['A', 'C']]
```

Fetching the data from dataframe `df`:

```
data =  [
    list(lists)
    for lists in zip(*(df[path].apply(list, axis=1) for path in paths))
]
```

```
[[['A1', 'B1', 'D1'], ['A1', 'B1', 'E1'], ['A1', 'C1']],
 [['A2', 'B2', 'D2'], ['A2', 'B2', 'E2'], ['A2', 'C2']]]
```

This should work for a *tree* with *root* `'A'` (actually, `if node not in path` isn't needed in this case - just looking ahead, trying to avoid infinite cycling). But what about a graph like this:

```
G = {
    'A': ['B', 'C'], 'B': ['D', 'E'], 'C': [], 'D': [], 'E': [],
    'F': ['G'], 'G': ['A'],
    'H': ['I'], 'I': ['J', 'K'], 'J': [], 'K': []
}
```

- `'F'` leads to `'G'` and `'G'` back to `'F'`, i.e. `G` has a *cycle*: What should happen?
- And you can't reach `'H'` from `'A'` (`G` is not *connected*): Should it be in the output or not?
- ...

Here's an adaption

```
paths = []
used = set()
for node in G:
    if node in used:
        continue
    stack = [[node]]
    used.add(node)
    while stack:
        path = stack.pop()
        nodes = G[path[-1]]
        if nodes:
            for node in reversed(nodes):
                if node not in used:
                    stack.append(path + [node])
                    used.add(node)
        else:
            if len(path) > 1:
                paths.append(path)
```

which includes paths for each component, starting at the first node in the component, that lead to dead ends. Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'E'], ['A', 'C'],
 ['H', 'I', 'J'], ['H', 'I', 'K']]
```

Comment: Thanks Timus, I guess in my case, the graphs cannot be cyclical, maybe I should have referred to them as trees. But interesting extension !
I really like the pythonic solution, for people who are interested in an out of the box solution i found the package networkx.

g = nx.DiGraph(graph_dictionary)
list(nx.algorithms.all_simple_paths(g, 'A', leafs))

where leafs is a list of all the nodes in the graph that are not linked ['C', 'D', 'E'] which gives [['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'E'], ['A', 'C']], then querying the data frame in your fashion to finish up.

Comment: @Azorx `networkx` is great, I used to work with it a lot. I decided against using it here, since it's more fun so see the logic at work ;)